# How would one get a custom attribute with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, custom-attributes

We have a custom attribute on checkboxes in this case called data-ref.

How would one get the value. This did not work.

```
this.attr('data-ref');
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: Well, if it's called "date-ref", then you probably don't want to select "data-ref", so I hope one of those is a typo in your question!

Comment: Well, your question states that the attribute is called "date-ref" (with an e) and your jQuery is looking for "data-ref" (with an a). I don't mean to be smarmy, but is that the issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're aware that you have a discrepancy between your custom attribute 'date-ref' in your text, and 'data-ref' in your jQuery?

Also, you might find it easier to work with the jQuery object:

```
$(this).attr('data-ref');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5ASKr/).

The problem, indeed, seems to be that you weren't using a jQuery object:

```
this.attr('data-ref');
```

[Can't work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5ASKr/1/)

On the other hand, to retrieve `data-*` attributes using the DOM, you do have the options of:

```
this.getAttribute('data-ref');
```

Or:

```
this.dataset.ref;
```

Or:

```
this.dataset['ref'];
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("selector").attr("data-ref");`

Should definitly work.

Maybe you can post your html code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you must use:

```
$(this).attr('data-ref');
```

but this is not very beautiful!
use [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store data to DOM nodes.

to store:

```
$('#divid').data('data-ref', 'i am data');
```

to get:

```
var data = $('#divid').data('data-ref');
```

Comment: With the ".data()" API, HTML5 "data-foo" attributes should be referenced as just "foo".

Answer (score 1):

The previously stated attr() is how to get the custom attributes. However, also note that if you are using HTML5's data-* attributes, you can also now leverage jQuery's .data() to acess that data:

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

your implementational problem may be with your use of this. maybe it should be $(this) or you may not be binding correctly. I cannot find any problems with it.. see http://jsfiddle.net/nvkVy/2/

```
<a href='api.fatherstorm.com' data-ref='test' data:ref='test' data_ref='test' class='testable'>test me</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.testable').click(function(){

       alert('data-ref='+$(this).attr('data-ref'));
        alert('data:ref='+$(this).attr('data:ref'));
        alert('data_ref='+$(this).attr('data_ref'));
        return(false);
    }); 
});
</script>
```